# Any reason why widgets/menus get emptied when I updated custom theme code?

Tags: menus, widgets, register-sidebar

Deployed my site over git last nite, and client came back saying some menus in the the footer widgets had disappeared. I looked in the admin, and the widgets were still available but all the items inside them were gone. How can I register widgets to not get emptied upon new code updates? Is this even a thing?

Comment: Impossible to say without hands on debug of theme and such. Widgets/menus are in general resilient enough that they _should_ survive theme update just fine.

Comment: relevant: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17979

Comment: What are the names of the sidebars in the old and the new themes? ( sidebar IDs, not the pretty human readable names shown in the widgets page )

Comment: @TomJNowell Indeed, very relevant. Thanks for pointing that report out.